# How can i use filter using Vue 2 which should be compatible for Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-filter

I am using  Vue js 2 + version and for my requirement i created a filter for date formatting but i heard that in Vue 3 filter got removed and instead need to use compute or method the problem here how can i write a compatible version for version 2 and version 3

**Vue js 2 filter i wrote**

```
<ul>
       
  <li v-for="(info, index) in data">
     {{info.time.data | Filter}}
  <li>
<ul>
```

Filter request :

```
    filters: {
  Filter(date){
     return moment.unix(date).utc().format('HH:mm a');
    
    }
  },
```

How can i write a compatible method which can be used for both version 2 & 3

Comment: it will work like that ?  i haven't tried just saw this   https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/filters.html#_2-x-syntax

Comment: Sorry, removed as I'm probably too drunk to think

Comment: actually ... `{{timeFilter(info.time.data)}}` does work - `timeFilter` being a method

Comment: @JaromandaX this  i need to created in computed or method ?

Comment: I did say it would be a method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated here https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/filters.html#overview - filters using pipe operators will not work in Vue 3, and have to be replaced with methods or computed properties.

It would work both on **Vue 2** and **Vue 3** if You put `timeFilter` into `methods` and change Your template replacing *pipe* with *method call*.

But probably computed property would be better optimized since it should cache values (resulting in less operations if input value hasn't changed).

```html
<ul>
  <li v-for="(info, index) in data" :key="index">
     {{ timeFilter(info.time.data) }}
  <li>
<ul>
```

```js
methods: {
  timeFilter(date) {
     return moment.unix(date).utc().format('HH:mm a');
  }
}
```

We can also use **global $filters** property as suggested in **migration strategy** (and also @Naren suggested).

In Vue 2 and Vue 3 templates:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="(info, index) in data" :key="index">
     {{ $filters.timeFilter(info.time.data) }}
  <li>
<ul>
```

In Vue 3:

```
// main.js
const app = createApp(App);

app.config.globalProperties.$filters = {
   timeFilter: date => moment.unix(date).utc().format('HH:mm a')
}
```

In Vue 2:

```js
Vue.prototype.$filters = {
   timeFilter: date => moment.unix(date).utc().format('HH:mm a')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Vue 3 does not support filters, As per Vue docs: `Filters are removed from Vue 3.0 and no longer supported.` But you can still use `computed properties` for data change listeners otherwise `methods` suffice. In case if you want to register them globally, use can do like the following

```
// main.js
const app = createApp(App)

app.config.globalProperties.$filters = {
   timeFilter: (date) => moment.unix(date).utc().format('HH:mm a')
}
```

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="(info, index) in data">
     {{ $filters.timeFilter(info.time.data) }}
  <li>
<ul>
```